# Speeding up an Euler numerical scheme in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

Let's say I have an update scheme that looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000
dt = 0.01

x = np.zeros(N)
x[0] = 0.5

for i in xrange(1, N):

    rand = np.random.normal(loc=0.,scale=1.)

    x[i] = x[i-1]*(1 + dt + np.sqrt(dt)*rand)
```

What is the best strategy for speeding up code of this form, where the current array element needs the previous array element to make the calculation?

I was attempting to put it into a vectorised form but I'm a bit stuck as to how to use the trailing array element to update the current one.

If there are better solutions that don't involve vectorisation I'm open to those too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
x = np.random.randn(1000)
x += 1
x[0] = 0.5
y = np.cumprod(x)
```

Answer in y

Comment: I tried to make sure it was the same. Could you help me understand the difference so I can fix it? (Or alternately post your own answer, if you prefer).

Comment: I see. Thanks! I've changed cumsum to cumprod. I think that should have it.